# Baffling "Object Required" issue

Tags: vba, excel

It's entirely possible -- probable, even -- that I'm missing something here, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.

I have a situation where I need a user defined structure (or a class, I guess, but I'm trying to stay simple) to carry two related bits of data: the column name and column number where certain data lives.

However, when I run the code, I get an "object required" error on the first assignment attempt:

Here's the truncated listing:

```
Public Type ConfigDataType
    ltr As String
    nbr As Integer
End Type

Sub MacroWorkbookName()
    Dim ProjCol, WBSCol, ResCol, ValCol As ConfigDataType
    Call GetParameters(ProjCol, WBSCol, ResCol, ValCol)
End Sub

Sub GetParameters(ByRef P, W, R, V As ConfigDataType)

    Dim MacroWorkBook As String
    MacroWorkBook = ThisWorkbook.Name

    ' The next line triggers the error
    P.ltr = Workbooks(MacroWorkBook).Sheets("Configuration").Cells(6, 3)
    W.ltr = Workbooks(MacroWorkBook).Sheets("Configuration").Cells(7, 3)
    R.ltr = Workbooks(MacroWorkBook).Sheets("Configuration").Cells(8, 3)
    V.ltr = Workbooks(MacroWorkBook).Sheets("Configuration").Cells(9, 3)

End Sub
```

I'm either fundamentally misunderstanding something about VBA syntax, or I've missed some braindead error.

It's also possible I'm going about this All Wrong in terms of idiomatic Excel automation, in which case I also welcome nudges towards the True Path - the client will presumably use this for a while, and I'd hate for them to think ill of me for deploying crappy code.

Comment: You have to explicitly declare variable types for **every** variable.  Your line `P, W, R, V As ConfigDataType` only declares `V`, all of the others (P, W, and R) are defaulting to `Variant` instead of ConfigDataType

Comment: Aha.

So the right syntax is more like `Sub GetParams(byRef P as ConfigDataType, W as ConfigDataType...`, etc?

Does the initial Dim work as I expect it to, i.e. does it create ProjCol, WBSCol, ValCol, and ResCol as variables of type ConfigDataType?

Comment: For your first question: Yes, that is the correct syntax.  For your second question: No, the same logic applies and you would still need to declare every variable type explicitly

Comment: Ah, apparently not. I'll mark this answered. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

TigerAvatar immediately saw my problem. I was assuming a line like

```
Dim foo, bar, bash, baz as ConfigType
```

would result in four variables of type ConfigType, but that's not the case. Only the last one is; the rest are of type variant. The correct usage is apparently

```
Dim foo as ConfigDataType, bar as ConfigDataType, bash as ConfigDataType, bas as ConfigDataType
```

and that extends to the definition of the sub, too, which would correctly be written

```
Sub GetParameters(ByRef P as ConfigDataType, W as ConfigDataType, R as ConfigDataType, V As ConfigDataType)
```

Once I fixed both of those issues, the code worked as I expected. Thanks again to Tigeravatar for such a prompt answer.